# Why taking input with getchar() falls in infinite loop?

Tags: c, do-while, getchar

#### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter first letter?  ");
        ch=getchar();
        //scanf("%c", &ch);
    }
    while(ch!='A' || ch!='S' || ch!='M' || ch!='D');
    printf("\n terminate here");

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
Runtime error   time: 0 memory: 2160 signal:25
Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter     first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?  Enter first letter?
```

I tried all possible ways but no luck. The `scanf()` is also not working. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: `while(ch!='A' || ch!='S' || ch!='M' || ch!='D');` This is not going to be false for any input . So what @BLUEPIXY suggested is to be done in order to make this condition false for an input and stop the loop .

Comment: What Bluepixy said: The condition `!(a || b || c)` is `(!a && !b && !c)`.

Comment: E.g when ch is 'A' , `ch!='A'` is false. `ch != 'S'` is  true. So `ch!='A' || ch!='S'` is true. also when ch is not 'A', `ch!='A'` is true. So `ch!='A' || ch!='S'` is true. so always true.(infinite in while loop)

Comment: at least it should prompt for input? where the hell did it get input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you gave `A` as input, then the first condition did not satisfied, but the other conditions are satisfied. Same is true for `S`, `M` and `O`.

It seemed to me that you are trying to stop your while loop when you get one of the above four letters. It can be done in various way like `ch!='A' && ch!='S' &&ch!='M' && ch!='D'` or `!(ch!='A' || ch!='S' ||ch!='M' ||ch!='D')`.

I used the second one in the code as it needs little change in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter first letter?  ");
        ch=getchar();
        getchar(); // extra getchar
//scanf("%c", &ch);
    }
    while(!(ch!='A' || ch!='S' ||ch!='M' ||ch!='D'));
    printf("\n terminate here");

    return 0;
}
```

#### N.B.

You have to give an extra `getchar()` because after inputting a letter you are giving enter button. The second `getchar()` is for taking this new line(`\n`) and ignoring. If you assign the input from second `getchar()` in a variable and print the ASCII character, you would find the same value of `\n`.

Comment: You have explained what is wrong but not mentioned and correction to OP .

Comment: @ameyCU explanation of correction added. Thanks.

Comment: @manetsus I get you but I am still not be able to scan input although the infinite loop had stoped. when i run i get following msg `Success time: 0 memory: 2164 signal:0
Enter first letter?  
 terminate here` . it does not wait for input.

Comment: @rkm_Hodor_king did you try appending an extra `getchar()` after `ch=getchar();` line?

Comment: why i need to add extra? if i add it be two `getchar();` for input.

Comment: @rkm_Hodor_king updated.

Answer (score 1):

You loop condition is logically always true. You accept only one character, but your condition is true while the entered characted is different from any of the following: 'A', 'S', 'M', 'D'. You need to correct this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter first letter?  ");
        ch = getchar();
        //scanf("%c", &ch);
    } while (ch != 'A' && ch != 'S' && ch != 'M' && ch != 'D');
    printf("\n terminate here");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `do-while` statement is always true.
2. So it enters into the infinite loop

reason if `ch != 'A'` its false and condition its true and if `ch!='A'` is true then the loop is true either way its true.

Solution: use and logic i.e instead of `||` use `&&`.